# Check how the application has been launched?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

My question is simple - is it possible with the Python to check, which way application has been launched/spawned?

More information:

I got an application `something.exe` and now I need to check if the `something.exe` has been launched whether by the user or rather with some third party application running it as a child process.

Is it possible to check?

Comment: Why is this important to know? When you say code launched by a "third-party" do you mean importing the python module or actually running the app independantly?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I think he trying to detect debuger.

Answer (score 2):

With standard library it is not possible in windows. In Unix-like all processes (excepting init) have a parent.

```
import os
parent = os.getppid()
```

You can try to check `os.environ`. Different methods to run can set slightly different environment or not set any variable.

Also look at [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/). It has many functions for process management.

Comment: Do you mean that the `os.getppid()` would not work on Windows?

Comment: @Lucas I am using Python2. Changed in version 3.2: Added support for Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Python 2.7 version.

Answer (score 2):

I tried on Windows using [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) this approach:

```
import psutil

def get_process_mode(process_name):
    process_mode = None
    plist = psutil.get_process_list()
    for process in plist:
        try:
            if process.name == process_name:
                if process.parent:
                    process_mode = "third party app"
                else:
                    process_mode = "user launched"
                break
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
            print "'%s' Process is not allowing us to check its parent!" % process
    return process_mode
```

`get_process_mode("something.exe")`

But it didn't worked good in some cases...

Comment: Note that on the code above I'm getting the list of all processes and checking if there exists a process with the given name, then if the process has parent, it's a third party app, in other case it's an user launched app. The AccessDenied exception must be handled on Windows, because some processes are launched using the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user and those processes are not readable.

Comment: Unfortunately... `'psutil.Process(pid=8680)' Process is not allowing us to check its parent!` for the `get_process_mode(__file__)`.